# how to simplify this code? (Node JS using sqlite) IDE: Notepad++ Database: DB Browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sqlite

Pls help me simplify this. My program has many fields stored on the database (about 100 per table) and i think it is not a good idea.

This is my code

```js
 eacode = req.body.eacode;
 hcn = req.body.hcn;
 shsn = req.body.shsn;
 name = req.body.name;
 TENURHWS = req.body.TENURHWS;
 TENURLOT = req.body.TENURLOT;
 DWELTYPE = req.body.DWELTYPE;
 DWELTYPE_OTH = req.body.DWELTYPE_OTH;
 ROOF = req.body.ROOF;
 ROOF_OTH = req.body.ROOF_OTH;
 WALL = req.body.WALL;
 WALL_OTH = req.body.WALL_OTH;
 FLOOR = req.body.FLOOR;
 BEDROOM = req.body.BEDROOM;

db.run("INSERT INTO form12(name,TENURHWS,TENURLOT,DWELTYPE,DWELTYPE_OTH,ROOF,ROOF_OTH,WALL,WALL_OTH,FLOOR,BEDROOM) VALUES $name,$TENURHWS,$TENURLOT,$DWELTYPE,$DWELTYPE_OTH,$ROOF,$ROOF_OTH,$WALL,$WALL_OTH,$FLOOR,$BEDROOM)",
      { 
       $name : name,
  $TENURHWS : TENURHWS,
  $TENURLOT : TENURLOT,
  $DWELTYPE : DWELTYPE,
  $DWELTYPE_OTH : DWELTYPE_OTH,
  $ROOF : ROOF,
  $ROOF_OTH : ROOF_OTH,
  $WALL : WALL,
  $WALL_OTH : WALL_OTH,
  $FLOOR : FLOOR,
  $BEDROOM : BEDROOM
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

When your code is getting too long to manually typed out each part, see if you can use a loop to achieve a similar result.  In your example, if `req.body` only has keys which should be saved to the database, you could use the following code:

```
var fieldNames = req.body.keys();

// You could also store a manually maintained list of fields in you own list.
// var fieldNames = ["field1", "field2", "field3", ... , "fieldn"];

sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO form12(" + fieldNames.join(",") + ") Values (";

for(var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
    // Add other logic for building the values part
    sqlStatement += "'" + req.body[fieldNames[i]] + "', ";
}

// Remove trailing comma

sqlStatement += ")";
```

Comment: hi, can i ask where will i put the db.run() ?

Comment: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near ")": syntax error
    at Error (native) ........ i think it is an error on sqlstatement line

Comment: print out the resulting sql statement so we can see why it's not working